# Content generated by my factories aren't being picked up in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, factory-bot

I'm going crazy over a basic cucumber script I'm trying to implement. All I want to do is pretend to add some stuff in the database and then use cucumber to check that the data is appearing within my views. I know for a fact that data would be correctly represented in the view if the data actually existed, but using FactoryGirl is messing something up.

Here's what I'm doing:

features/news.feature:

```
Scenario: News on the home page
  Given a news article exists with the title "I love mung"
  When I go to the root page
  Then I should see "I love mung" within ".news"
```

features/step_definitions/news_steps.rb:

```
Given /^a news article exists with the title "([^"]+)"$/ do |title|
  # I've added the FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods to the `World`
  create :news, title: title

  # If I check the data here, it seems to think everything is ok
  expect(News.find_by(title: title).title).to eql title
end
```

app/views/info/welcome.html.erb

```
<% if news_article %>
  <!-- This element never displays (according to cucumber) -->
  <div class="news">
    <h3><%= news_article.title %></h3>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How are `news_article` and `article` defined for the view?

Comment: Whoops... There's a typo there. They should both be named the same. The news article is literally the last inserted article.

Comment: Ok, but I'm still wondering about (i.e. asking to see :-)), the code that defines `news_article`.

Comment: Oh bugger.. I've just noticed that the factory isn't putting the published flag on the articles by default. Solved.